# How to implement slug in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, slug

I am having a problem how to display slug data in view file i am using cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

**Model:**

```
use Sluggable;

public function sluggable() {
   return ['slug'=>[
       'source'=>'title',
       'onUpdate'=>true
   ]];
}

public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    self::creating(function($model){
        $model->slug = Str::slug($model->title, '-');
    });
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get("tenderview", "TenderViewController@show")->name('tenderview');

Route::get('/tenderview', 'TenderViewController@index')->name('tenderview');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    return view('tenderview');
}

public function show()
{
    $dataa = Kind::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(8);

    return view('tenderview',['dataa'=>$dataa]);
}
```

View file
@foreach($dataa as $dater)
{{$dater->name}}
@endforeach

How can i show slug in my view instead of displaying data as a whole, i want to display a link to the actual data. Thank you

Comment: This bit is quite confusing for me on what you actually want to achieve. "How can i show slug in my view instead of displaying data as a whole, i want to display a link to the actual data. Thank you" Can you come with an example of what the result should be?

Comment: I am trying to create slug in laravel @mrhn

Comment: We know, but what do you want to be shown in your view, you are setting ->slug but using name there?

Comment: Hi @mrhn thanks for your time, i want to make it like this one on the webiste https://selibeng.com/

Comment: When you click on the title of the post then it directs you to the view with all details of the post, i updated my question for how i want to display all details in view

Answer (score 0):

You could try with:

```
@foreach($dataa as $dater)
    <a href="{{ url('tenderview/'.$dater->slug) }}">{{ $dater->name }}</a>
@endforeach
```

**Route**:

```
Route::get("tenderview/{slug}", "TenderViewController@show")->name('tenderview.show');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $kind = Kind::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    if ($kind === null) { // not found
        return redirect()->route('tenderview');
    }

    return view('tenderview.show', ['kind' => $kind]);
}
```

**tenderview.show:**

```
<h1>{{ $kind->name }}</h1>
<p>{{ $kind->description }}</p>
```

Comment: Hi @MorganFreeFarm thank you very much for the answer i am working on it now except one thing, i am not sure whre to add the <h1> and <p> tags or should i create another blade file and name it show

Comment: It throws back this error Undefined variable: dataa (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project104\resources\views\tenderview.blade.php)

Comment: @MohailaTlaba `$dataa` is part of your code, check why it's undefined.